# Jacobian of hidden state update in backpropagation through time

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to understand the gradients of backpropagation through time for a simple recurrent neural network. In particular this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5063 (Section 1.1)

(Also here: https://cs224d.stanford.edu/lectures/CS224d-Lecture8.pdf and other blog posts that just refer to the chain rule.

EDIT: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html page 379)

The update for the "hidden state" is:
$$\mathbf{x}_t=\mathbf{W}\sigma(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) + \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{in}}\mathbf{u}_t + \mathbf{b}$$

Calculating the gradients makes sense up to the step when it comes to
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}_i}{\partial\mathbf{x}_{i-1}} = \mathbf{W}^\top diag(\sigma'(\mathbf{x}_{i-1})$$

Why is it $\mathbf{W}^\top$? I tried to come to the same result for a simple 2x2 example but I get a different result:

$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{W}\sigma(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix} w_{1,1} & w_{1,2} \\ w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sigma(x_1) \\ \sigma(x_2)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} w_{1,1}\sigma(x_1) + w_{1,2}\sigma(x_2)\\ w_{2,1}\sigma(x_1) +  w_{2,2}\sigma(x_2)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} w_{1,1}\sigma'(x_1) & w_{1,2}\sigma'(x_2)\\ w_{2,1}\sigma'(x_1) &  w_{2,2}\sigma'(x_2)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} w_{1,1} & w_{1,2} \\ w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sigma'(x_1) & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma'(x_2)\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{W} diag(\sigma'(\mathbf{x}))$$
This is also what I would expect applying the chain rule (with $\mathbf{z}=\sigma(\mathbf{x})$):
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{z}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{W}\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =\mathbf{W} diag(\sigma'(\mathbf{x})) $$

What am I missing / doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're right. The paper seems to use the [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#/Numerator-layout_notation) as the chain rule expands rightwards, which is the same as your calculations. So, for example, if the equation was $x=Wz$, and we were interested in $\frac{\partial Wz}{\partial z}$, the answer would have been $W$, not $W^T$. You can look at the third entry [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Matrix_calculus#/Vector-by-vector_identities). This simple example assumes $\sigma(z)=z$.

I'm pretty surprised that the analysis in the paper follows *incorrectly*. Nevertheless, that way would still show a lot about the exploding/vanishing gradients.